# Replace the value of a specific key in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, and I want to cycle through them and replace one of the values. The value I'm replacing is a dictionary, and I want to replace it with one of the values from the same dictionary.

Below is one of the dictionaries in the list.

```
{'id': '123abc',
 'name': 'Metrics',
 'rows': 0,
 'columns': 0,
 'owner': {'id': 123, 'name': 'John Doe'},
 'dataCurrentAt': '2017-03-24T14:32:33Z',
 'createdAt': '2017-03-24T14:32:33Z',
 'pdpEnabled': False}
```

So I'm trying to replace the entire 'owner' value with just 'name' from the 'owner' dictionary. I hope that makes sense. Below is the section of the Python script where I have attempted to do this.

```
for dictionary in dataset_list:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if key == "owner":
            owner = value.get("name")
            value = owner
```

Comment: The thing that's going wrong for you is that `value` is just a copy of the value in the dictionary. If you change that, you just change what the variable of the name `value` points at. If you want to change the dictionary, you have to access the dictionary directly: `dict['owner'] = 'something else'`

Comment: `a.update({'owner': a.get('owner').get('name')})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, all what you need to do is:

```
dictionary["owner"] = dictionary["owner"]["name"]
```

This will change the value of the key "owner", to the value of the key "name".

Comment: I think it should be dictionary["owner"]["name"]

Answer (score 1):

```
A = {'id': '123abc', 'name': 'Metrics', 'rows': 0, 'columns': 0, 'owner': {'id': 123, 'name': 'John Doe'}, 'dataCurrentAt': '2017-03-24T14:32:33Z', 'createdAt': '2017-03-24T14:32:33Z', 'pdpEnabled': False}
A["owner"] = A["owner"]["name"]
print A
```

**Output:**

```
{'rows': 0, 'createdAt': '2017-03-24T14:32:33Z', 'name': 'Metrics', 'pdpEnabled': False, 'owner': 'John Doe', 'id': '123abc', 'columns': 0, 'dataCurrentAt': '2017-03-24T14:32:33Z'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> dataset_list = {'id': '123abc', 'name': 'Metrics', 'rows': 0, 'columns': 0, 'owner': {'id': 123, 'name': 'John Doe'}, 'dataCurrentAt': '2017-03-24T14:32:33Z', 'createdAt': '2017-03-24T14:32:33Z', 'pdpEnabled': False}
>>> for k,v in dataset_list.iteritems():
    if k == "owner":
        owner = v["name"]
        dataset_list[k] = owner


>>> dataset_list
{'rows': 0, 'createdAt': '2017-03-24T14:32:33Z', 'name': 'Metrics', 'pdpEnabled': False, 'owner': 'John Doe', 'id': '123abc', 'columns': 0, 'dataCurrentAt': '2017-03-24T14:32:33Z'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for dictionary in dataset_list:
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if key == "owner":
            dictionary["owner"] = dictionary["owner"]["name"]
```